# check if String Date (mm/dd/yyyy) is weekend - bash

Tags: bash, date

I have nested for loops going through dates and create a date. How can I check if that specific date is on the weekend or not?

String date is in the format of mm/dd/yyyy but can easily be changed. Each has its own variable $m $d $y

```
if [[ $(date +%u) -gt 5 ]] ; then
   #do something
fi
```

above code works with current date, not sure how to translate that to accepting a string date.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: my entire research effort has lead to dead ends, only solutions using the date object for your current time and no work with string based dates.

Comment: I would have voted down if you hadn't corrected your comment. This might help with GNU date: `date -d "11/10/2019" +%u`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Ruby `Date#cwday` in your bash script. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
y=2019                                                                     
m=11
d=10
ruby -rtime -e "puts ([6,7].include? Date.new($y,$m,$d).cwday)"
```

which outputs `true`

Comment: Cool, that works perfectly only need to set Sat/Sun as weekend. So [6,7] not [1,7]

Answer (score 0):

I like more to use the variable directly:

```
  if [[ $(date -d $your_variable +%u) -gt 5 ]]; then
     #do something
  fi
```

Just makes the code cleaner in my opinion.